# What is the most hard to understand piece of C++ code you know?

Tags: c++

Today at work we came across the following code (some of you might recognize it):

```
#define GET_VAL( val, type ) \
    {                                                   \
        ASSERT( ( pIP + sizeof(type) ) <= pMethodEnd ); \
        val = ( *((type *&)(pIP))++ );                  \
    }
```

Basically we have a byte array and a pointer. The macro returns a reference to a variable of type and advance the pointer to the end of that variable.

It reminded me of the several times that I needed to "think like a parser" in order to understand C++ code.

Do you know of other code examples that caused you to stop and read it several times till you managed to grasp what it was suppose to do?

Comment: No its not - I wrote this question so that we can show interesting and confusion ways of using C++. So we can learn from those examples.

Comment: This comments about questions getting closed are ridiculous.

Comment: At any rate, this should be community wiki.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The inverse square root implementation in Quake 3:

```
float InvSqrt (float x){
    float xhalf = 0.5f*x;
    int i = *(int*)&x;
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);
    x = *(float*)&i;
    x = x*(1.5f - xhalf*x*x);
    return x;
}
```

**Update:**
[How this works](http://www.lomont.org/Math/Papers/2003/InvSqrt.pdf) (thanks ryan_s)

Comment: Don't forget to link Chris Lamont's paper for the great explanation of how this crazy thing works.
http://www.lomont.org/Math/Papers/2003/InvSqrt.pdf

Comment: Would above still work? or is there any undefined behavior (which would make it to just work in some specific compilers)

Comment: why didn't you include the comments  : (

Answer (score 34):

This was on reddit recently   http://www.eelis.net/C++/analogliterals.xhtml

```
 assert((o-----o
        |     !
        !     !
        !     !
        !     !
        o-----o ).area == ( o---------o
                            |         !
                            !         !
                            o---------o ).area );
```

Comment: Now *this* is why I love C++ !

Comment: Link is now broken :(

Comment: @JaredBurrows - thanks, found a new one

Answer (score 16):

Duff's Device (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) give me nightmares:

```
strcpy(to, from, count)
char *to, *from;
int count;
{
    int n = (count + 7) / 8;
    switch (count % 8) {
    case 0: do { *to = *from++;
    case 7:      *to = *from++;
    case 6:      *to = *from++;
    case 5:      *to = *from++;
    case 4:      *to = *from++;
    case 3:      *to = *from++;
    case 2:      *to = *from++;
    case 1:      *to = *from++;
            } while (--n > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've always found Duff's Device quite intuitive, it just makes sense. After you get over the weird syntax of the loop you're rolling, or unrolling perhaps :)

Comment: I think this is easier to understand if you've programmed assembly than if you've come from a non-assembly background.

Answer (score 11):

I know it's C and not C++ but there is always the the [International Obfuscated C Code Contest](http://www.ioccc.org/).  I have seen some code there that would make your head spin.

Answer (score 10):

This is well known but still impressive way to swap two integers without creating temp variable:

```
// a^=b^=a^=b;     // int a and int b will be swapped
// Technically undefined behavior as variable may only 
// be assined once within the same statement.
// 
// But this can be written correctly like this.
// Which still looks cool and unreadable ;-)

a^=b;
b^=a;
a^=b;
```

Comment: only problem is that this is technically undefined behavior due to sequence point rules. use "a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b;" instead.

Comment: Wrong. it is correct. Operation order is perfectly defined from right to left in this case. Read the standard,

Comment: @ Terminus: You are infact wrong. Assigning to a variable more than once in a statement is undefined behavior. To prevent this you need to use the ';' to seporate them into different statements.

Comment: Actually you need to study the C/C++ standard. Why do you state things you don't know about? Read about associativity: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence '=' has right to left associativity. This site is supposed to give EXPERT answers. You just demonstrate your ignorance in C/C++.

Comment: This is realy really really basic stuff. You shouldn't be talking about C/C++ when you don't know this. You are just spreading false ideas.

Comment: You can also read here some stuff: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#Note_about_right-associative_operators

Comment: int a = 10, b = 45;
a^=b^=a^=b;
std::cout << a << "\t" << b;

That gave the correct output: 45    10

Comment: @Terminus: The problem has nothing to do with associativity. The problem is with sequence points.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point. Unfortunately Sequence points and optimizations are really complex stuff and you need to be a compiler engineer to really understand them (like myself).

Comment: @Esteban: The behavior is undefined. This means the compiler may or may not do the correct thing, and could even change depending on the optimization level you are using.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, you are 100% right. I thought only about associativity and neglected sequence points. You can't modify the same variable twice between 2 sequence points. You are 100% correct :-). Sorry about the noise.

Comment: You can still use the comma operator if you want to do all that in a single instruction, though ;-).

Comment: Wow! Who could of thought that such simple expression will raise such complicated debate :-)
P.S. for ignorant VC++ coder the original form works fine though.

Comment: @Ma99uS: It may look and work fine (See Esteban's comments above). But technically it is undefined. The compiler is free to do anything it likes. Assuming VC++ implements C++.

Comment: Similar idea, without XOR: `a -= b; b += a; a = b - a;`

Answer (score 10):

```
unsigned int reverse(register unsigned int x)
{
 x = (((x & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((x & 0x55555555) << 1));
 x = (((x & 0xcccccccc) >> 2) | ((x & 0x33333333) << 2));
 x = (((x & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((x & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4));
 x = (((x & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((x & 0x00ff00ff) << 8));
 return((x >> 16) | (x << 16));
}
```

Reverses the order of the bits in an int.

Comment: If this had been clever trick code then +1.

Comment: It's actually not very hard to understand what this does because of the function name. It's _how_ it's done that's tricky.

Comment: This is more bit twiddling rather obscure C code.

Answer (score 7):

Most Boost stuff - the template metaprogramming is bad enough, but when you factor in the workarounds necessary to get it to work on some compilers (*coughborlandcough*), it gets pretty ridiculous. Just try to understand Boost.Bind. Just try.

Answer (score 3):

C, but present in C++, I find the comma operator really obfuscates code, take this...

```
ihi = y[0]>y[1] ? (inhi=1,0) : (inhi=0,1);
```

Terse and quite elegant, but very easy to miss or misunderstand.

Comment: To me, this code is a perfect example of "Just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should." It's neat because it's on one line, but if it was spread out more it would be many times more understandable by someone look at it for the first time.

Not that it's not a cool example. :)

Comment: I think the biggest issue here is with the naming. `ihi` could be short for `index_high` (as in, the index of the higher value), but I have no clue why `inhi` is named that way, as it's actually `index_low`.

Comment: A shorter way to do it: `int index_low = y[0]>y[1], index_high = !index_low;`

Still not as clear as  an `if/else` (which a compiler would make fast anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Anything prefixed with:

[/* You are not expected to understand this */](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/odd.html)

Comment: Cached version: https://archive.is/eeYMW#30%

Answer (score -3):

Binary shift confuses me all the time. An example from the `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` package:

```
return ((h << 7) - h + (h >>> 9) + (h >>> 17))
```

Comment: Why has this been voted up?  This is Java, but the question is about C++.

Answer (score -6):

I vote for some black-magic-hackerish template metaprogramming (unfortunately don't have any on hand to post it).